# MS Access tag merge/alias

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

We've got:

- `msaccess` - 31
- `ms-access` - 4
- `microsoft-access` - 2

I'd say that `ms-access` or `microsoft-access` would be the better tag, but the people have spoken, and `msaccess` is the most common option.

Answer (score 4):

I think we should keep it consistent with the existing tags `ms-office`, `ms-project` etc. and keep only

`ms-access`.

I've merged the three tags and created the corresponding synonyms.